# a custom web part contains telerik mossradeditor controls. but this custom is not showing in sharepoint 2007 add web part page

Tags: telerik, sharepoint-2007, radeditor

I have created a custom web-part that contains telerik mossradeditor control. but this webpart is not displaying inside the add web-part page of SharePoint 2007.

this is happening only my prod environment but its working in stage and development environment.

Installed radeditorsharepoint version 5.5.1.0.

Please help me to resolve this..

Answer (score 0):

Examine their online documentation and make sure you are following the appropriate steps: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/moss-installing-radeditor-in-moss-2007-farm.html.

You need to have it installed on production as well, you may have missed some files.

About your own webparts, not the one Telerik provide - make sure it deploys properly. Check assembly references and make sure they use the correct versions. You may need a bindingRedirect in the site's web.config.